# jmeter 2.9 won't open my script built with jmeter 2.8

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a script that works (opens and runs) perfectly fine in 2.8 version of jmeter. I just downloaded Jmeter 2.9 and I am unable to open this script.

I am getting the following error on the log file and I don't seem to understand what the problem is with DummySampler which seems to be the source of the error as per the log.
I checked the 2.9 version change log page http://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html and don't find anything relevant.

I am new to Jmeter and Java, Appreciate any help!

```
2013/08/05 17:12:29 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: All converter versions present and correct 
2013/08/05 17:12:30 ERROR - jmeter.save.SaveService: Conversion error com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.DummySampler : kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.DummySampler
---- Debugging information ----
message             : kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.DummySampler
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.DummySampler
class               : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[7]/hashTree[6]/kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.DummySampler
line number         : 416
------------------------------- : kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.DummySampler : kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.DummySampler
---- Debugging information ----
message             : kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.DummySampler
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.DummySampler
class               : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[7]/hashTree[6]/kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.DummySampler
line number         : 416
-------------------------------
message             : kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.DummySampler : kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.DummySampler
---- Debugging information ----
message             : kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.DummySampler
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.DummySampler
class               : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[7]/hashTree[6]/kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.DummySampler
line number         : 416
-------------------------------
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
cause-message       : kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.DummySampler : kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.DummySampler
first-jmeter-class  : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:65)
class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[7]/hashTree[6]/kg.apc.jmeter.samplers.DummySampler
line number         : 416
version             : 2.9 r1437961
------------------------------- 
2013/08/05 17:12:30 WARN  - jmeter.gui.action.Load: Unexpected error java.lang.Exception: Error in TestPlan - see log file
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.insertLoadedTree(Load.java:158)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:113)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.doAction(Load.java:92)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:81)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.access$000(ActionRouter.java:40)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter$1.run(ActionRouter.java:63)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:676)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:674)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:685)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use a thrid party plugin JMeter-plugins.

Ensure you added the required jars in lib/ext and their dependencies in lib

Comment: Thanks that helps. I thought I copied over all jars I had on 2.8. my bad I missed a couple of them on the ext folder under the lib. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

I had same kind of situation, jmx won't load. Only the error was different, I got: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

This was fixed by installing Java SE 1.7.0.67

Answer (score -2):

You should change your JMX manually as there is different format. You can read about [JMX format](http://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JmxTestPlan).

Comment: I am sorry, I don't follow. My script that works in 2.8 version of jmeter is also .jmx file. What changes do I need to make?

Comment: Open Jmeter 2.9 and try to add your Test plan manually. After save and compare two jmx files, you should see difference.